# vimeo iframe for IOS how to hide "like" and "share" button from right side of UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, vimeo, vimeo-api

i am using UIWebview to play vimeo video by using this code
let embedHTML = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+(str)!+"?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=008efe&amp\";controls=0&fullscreen=1&buttons.share = flase&embed.buttons.like = false;autoplay=1&loop=1 width=\"375\" height=\"370\" frameborder=\"0\">"
i need to hide "share" and "like" button

Answer (score 8):

According to [Hiding the share button on vimeo help](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/229326167-Share-features):

> You **cannot hide the Share button** from your public videos on vimeo.com.
>   However, viewers of private videos (videos with a **privacy setting
>   other than "Anyone"**) do **not see the Share button** on the video page.
>   Only video owners see the Share button on the video pages of their
>   private videos.
>
> **Plus, PRO, and Business members can customize the embedded video
>   player to hide the Share button.**

For me the only solution was to change the setting in my vimeo PRO/Business account for the particular video. The iframe url parameters did not change anything in regards to the share buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo also allows you to embed the video on specific domains that you may specify. Using this combination removes the option to share the embedded video. It enables those logged in on the domain to access for viewing.

Answer (score -1):

this can be help full  take a look

```
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="projectplayer" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/336413453"></iframe>

<script>
iframe = $('#projectplayer')[0];
player = $f(iframe);
player.api('setVolume',1); //reset volume
</script>
```